# Enable installation location chooser when installing an application published on Azure blob storage

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-blob-storage, installation-path

I have a .Net desktop application published to Azure blob storage I followed this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2011/05/09/how-to-deploy-clickonce-application-using-windows-azure-storage-in-very-simple-steps/) to do so. The user can install the application by accessing a public blob link e.g.: https://root.blob.core.windows.net/appcontainer/publish.htm

By default, the application is installed to

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0

My question is, how to change the default installation path? or how can I make the user choose the installation location if applicable?

I'm using visual studio 2015 to publish the desktop application

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how to change the default installation path? or how can I make the user choose the installation location if applicable?

As far as I know, for privilege and security concern, ClickOnce always install an application in the user Application Cache per user, and it does not enable user to choose the installation location. If you’d like to enable user to install application with a user specified installation location, you could use other installer technology.